# Does successfully opening the vault end your movement due to drawing the item cards?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

The inside of the vault has icons that draw cards, so once you've cracked it does your movement stop? (Obviously it has already stopped if you only just discovered the vault and drew an event card, so I'm referring to when it isn't newly discovered.)

I know movement is stopped when drawing a card from discovering a new room with a card symbol. The rules and the errata/FAQ mention stopping movement "upon drawing a card" (usually from room discovery) so I've been interpreting it to apply in this case as well on the merit that it's "drawing a card", and from a room icon no less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, drawing a card **for any reason** ends your movement.

As you pointed out, [the rules](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/HOTH_Rules.zip) (page 5) make it clear that drawing a room tile with a card symbol does this:

> The first time you discover a room with a card symbol, you must end your move in that room and draw the appropriate card.

The rules for movement (page 4) clarify this further:

> Whenever a game effect makes you draw a card, you must STOP moving for the rest of your turn.

So any game effect which makes you draw cards (and if you're not cheating you should only be drawing cards based on 'game effects'!) ends your movement. This includes things such as successfully opening the puzzle box item, so try that at the end of your turn unless you really need the item!

Comment: You're right! It says it right near the beginning under "Move", actually quite prominently. Not sure how I missed that. Good call, thanks!

Comment: FYI my edition (2nd?) actually even says: "However, whenever a game effect makes you draw a card **for any reason**, you must stop moving for the rest of your turn." just as you wrote at the top.

Answer (score 1):

The rules don't give a clarification on this exact point, but as you say, the wording is that you stop moving when you draw a card. I have always interpreted that literally, so if you draw a card from the vault or by any other means, you must stop moving.